# Overwrite results div if single result selected, and append if multiple selected

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a table with records from an api which displays users data. The image of the user is not displayed in the table, but displayed in a separate div on tr click.

```
<div id='users'>
<div class='users-details'>
<table>
 <tr><td id='1' class='user'>User 1</td></tr>
 <tr><td id='2' class='user'>User 2</td></tr>
 <tr><td id='3' class='user'>User 2</td></tr>
 <tr><td id='4' class='user'>User 2</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
<div class="holder-container">
<div class='preview-holder'>
<!-- user data pushed to here -->
  <div class='user-prev'>
   // users details displayed here
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The above works and overrides the data to the .user-prev div when selecting a single user row. Now my issues is when selecting multiple td's. What i would like to do is clear user-prev and clone .preview-holder depending on the selected td .user.

For example, if i select user1 tr .user, display user 1 details. When selecting user2, user3, user4, clear previous results from .user-prev, duplicate it 3 times and update results as per each selected tr.user.

I have the below code which was giving issues, when selecting multiple it sometimes duplicates and not clearing the first results

```
$(document).on("click", ".user", function (event) {
 var selected = []; // store selected users id
 $('.user-prev').html(''); // clear div empty
 for (var i = 0; i < ids_arr.length; ++i)
 selected .push({UserIds: ids_arr[i]});
 $.ajax({
  url: "/db/user_api.php",
  data: { func_name: "getUsers", rows: $.toJSON(selected)},
  type: 'post',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(res)
  {
   for (var i = 0; i < res.length; ++i) 
   {
     var x = res[i].result[0];
     var count = $("tr.user.selected").length;
   }
   if (count == 1)
    {
      $(".user-prev").html(x.UserName); // display user name, also returns pics
    }
    if (count > 1)
    {
     // duplicate/clone the div as many times as selected [] and populate each user-prev with selected name
       $(".user-prev").clone().append(x.UserName);      }
  }
 });
});
```

TIA

Comment: Looks like you never reset `r` to empty so `push` just keeps adding to array `r`.

Comment: the  question ahs been updated, r was meant to be selected. I'm reusing code from another function but that doesn't have this functionality I want

Comment: I think you're going about this wrong. The `preview-holder` DIV should be initially empty. Then any time you select a user, it gets appended, you don't have to treat the first selection specially.

Comment: @Barmar, not sure if i am following you. I did try to create the <div class="user-prev">... within the js, there are other functionalities which must be attached to the user-prev div for specific returned data, ie image types and so forth, hence why i tried adding it to the html and clearing it onclick

Comment: `$(".user-prev").clone().append("x.UserName");` This must be a typo. It will append the string `"x.UserName"`

Comment: @RobMoll the typo has been fixed, thanks

Comment: Excuse me, what is `ids_arr`? Is it a global variable?

Comment: yes its a global array